# Превратить python с pyqt5 в exe

Tags: python, pyqt5, exe

Я создал приложение python с графической оболочкой на PYQT5. В нём множество модулей и библиотек, и он полностью работает. Как мне собрать его в exe? Можно ли превратить его сразу через QT Creator?

Comment: ознакомьтесь с документацией по использованию PyInstaller: 

  https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте с помощью pyinstaller.

В нём есть [опция `-F`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#what-to-generate) для сборки программы, всех её зависимостей и самого интерпретатора Python в один исполняемый файл.

Comment: команда pyinstaller -F -w name.py создает один exe-файл, для qt приложения, но не гарантирует , что он будет запускаться на другом компьютере.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри на это. Прикольная штука и на мой взгляд лучше чем pyinstaller
(хотя на вкус и цвет как говориться)

https://docs.beeware.org/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй библиотеку py2exe, она сделает рабочее приложение по Windows.

> https://github.com/py2exe/py2exe